# Advice on how to start a program using arrays, classes and methods to store student details in java?

Tags: java, arrays, class

I am stuck on how to break down this scenario. Could someone give me some guidance on how to start this and perhaps maybe give a little structure? I can do arrays, methods and classes but have no clue where to start and what should be in a class. Thank you!

> Create a solution for the following scenario: A local community mobile college unit holds 2 different classes in literacy and numeracy for mature students.  A student can join the mobile unit and sign up to one or both classes.  The students ID number, forename, surname, age and telephone no should be held on the system for initial sign up.
>
> Create a program using classes and methods that will start to build this system. An ultimate solution would be where the two courses can be set up and then students enrolled on the courses.  A menu system should allow for input of extra courses (in case of expansion) input of student details and students to enroll on courses. The menu should also allow a list of students by course, a list of all students by age.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: First, forget about arrays... So far, there are many different collections in Java that are much more flexible, fast and type-safe.

Comment: I have began with creating an array for the courses, this array holds up to 1000 records as the task requests the option to add courses. I have then created a while loop to allow it to keep asking if a new course should be added or for user to select "0" to exit loop.... now do I create a class for student info..?

Comment: he may not have learned anything more than arrays yet. sounds like an intro programming course.

Comment: it is... can anyone help?

Comment: The usual way you solve these things is _one step at a time_. Pick a part of the problem that you _can_ solve (perhaps describing a single student) and do that right. Then look at the rest of the problem and see if you can tackle it now, or if you need to bite off another piece first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Student {
   private int id;
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;
   private int yearOfBirth; 
   private String telephone;

   public Student(){ // public constructor
     yearOfBirth = -1;       // default value to indicate that age was not specified yet
   } 

   public setFirstName(String firstName) {
      this.firstName = firstName;
   }

   public setLastName(String lastName) {
      this.lastName = lastName;
   }

   public setAge(int age){
      // calculate approximate year of birth based on student's current age
      Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
      calendar.setTime(new Date());
      yearOfBirth = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) - age;
   }

   public setTelephone(String telephone){
      this.telephone = telephone;
   }

   /*
    add getters by yourself
   */

   @Override
   public String toString(){
      StringBuilder result;
      if (!getFirstName().equals("")){
          result.append(getFirstName());
      }
      if (!getLastName().equals("")){
          if (!result.equals("")){
             result.append(" ");
          }
          result.append(getLastName());
      }
      if (getAge() != -1){
         if (!result.equals("")){
            result.append(", ");
         }
         result.append("age: ").append(String.valueOf(getAge()));
      }
      if (!getTelephone().equals("")){
         if (!result.equals("")){
            result.append(", ");
         }
         result.append("telepnone: ").append(getTelepnone());
      }
      return result.toString();
   }
};
```

Comment: Thank you very useful. I have taken some elements from this to get a start on this program, I really appreciate the help :)

Comment: I've changed `toString()` method a little bit--to use more smart and effective `StringBuilder` class. Hope you enjoy!